# Sql Server Date show on Column wise Dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2005

My Sql Query is

```
select BookingDate from EntBookings 
where BookingDate between '01 Jan 2013' and '03 jan 2013'
```

and I want to Output the columns

```
1-jan  |  2-Jan  |  3-Jan
```

Comment: Is this query in a stored procedure? Have you considered dynamic query? And will the `BookingDate` have dates in continuity, meaning no dates will be missing in between?

Answer (score 0):

You had the date format wrong. use

```
select case when BookingDate = '2013-01-01' then BookingDate end as '1-jan',
            when BookingDate = '2013-01-02' then BookingDate end as '2-jan',
            when BookingDate = '2013-01-03' then BookingDate end as '3-jan'
from EntBookings 
where BookingDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-03'
```

Comment: i want dynamic columns according to filter date

Comment: Is it important to use text like 2-june but not 2-06-2012?

Comment: If `BookingDate` is a `date` then yes. You have to use the right format.